# "so think of him/her on" Tuesday

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-meaning

If your friend has a job interview, what does "**so think of** *him/her* **on** *Tuesday/Thursday/etc*" mean?

Does it mean like pray for him that they get the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that, probably. To "keep someone in your thoughts" is generally to wish that person well (which is akin to prayer in some ways). It may also imply a suggestion to try to think of ways to help, or maybe check up on that person after the time of hardship passes, if such a limited period of time is also implied, as it is in your example.

I should add that we're discussing implied meaning, not literal meaning. To "keep someone in your thoughts" literally means to keep (continue) thinking about that person, or more specifically, to keep that person in the set of subjects that you are thinking about. The set of subjects is implied by "your thoughts," since thoughts generally are directed at various, particular subjects. The thoughts don't have to be benevolent, but benevolence (as intended in praying for someone else's well-being) is probably intended, and implying a suggestion for benevolent or sympathetic thoughts and behaviors is probably the reason for making this suggestion to think of someone.